# Unvalid Grammar Exception when trying a Subquery in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

i have two entities Bid, and BidStatus, Bid has a OneToMany relationship with BidStatus

```
Set<BidStatus> Bid.bidStatuses [OneToMany]
Bid BidStatus.parentBid  [ManyToOne]
```

in term of attributes BidStatus has :

- label : String
- date : a date (LocalDate)

what i'am trying to do is select all Bids that have status whose label = status and date is between datebefore and dateafter.

for now i tried the following Query :

```
select b from Bid b 
    where b.statuses in (select S from BidStatus S 
                                WHERE 
                                            S.label  = :status 
                                        and S.date >= :before 
                                        and S.date <= :after)
```

but using this query i got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

**edit:**
i was able to make it run using the following query :

```
select b from Bid b 
            where EXISTS " +
                (select S from BidStatus S 
                    WHERE
                                S.label  = :status 
                            and S.date >= :before 
                            and S.date <= :after 
                            and S.parentBid = b)
```

but i still don't understand what was wrong with the first one.

Comment: "IN" is to be used for checking for the presence of an element in a Collection; you seem to want to check the presence of a Collection in a Collection - hence the error presumably. I also assume that "b.statuses" is "b.bidStatuses" to match the fields you say you have.

Comment: you're right i didn't use the IN operator correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

select a from A a 
        where a.bs in 
           (select b from B b 
              WHERE
                           b.X  = :param1
                       and b.Y >= :paramDate1
                       and b.Y <= :paramDate2)

you neend to use alias 'a' to refrence 'bs' rather than entity class name 'A' ie. a.bs rather than A.bs

Comment: thank you but that's not my issue, i tried simplifying the query but in doing so i clearly made it harder for you guys to help, so now i put in the actual query